# safari form error "formData@NativeCode" when using post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix, remix.run

I want to upload multiple photos and got following error ONLY IN SAFARI (Maybe macOS Systems). In all other browser it works.

Error is at the bottom uploaded

Here is my code:

app.tsx

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    if(!e.target.files) {
      return;
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("images", e.target.files[i]);
      console.log(e.target.files[i]);
    }
    fetcher.submit(formData, { method: 'post', action: '/imagesAdd', encType: 'multipart/form-data' });
    // @ts-ignore
    document.querySelector('.fl').value = '';
  }

<input type="file" name="files" className="fl" multiple onChange={handleChange} />
```

imageAdd

```
import { ActionFunction, unstable_composeUploadHandlers, unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler, unstable_parseMultipartFormData } from "@remix-run/node";
import { uploadImage } from "~/data/upload.server";

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request, params }) => {
    try {
      const rq = request.clone();
      const fd = await rq.formData();

      console.log(fd.get('images'));
      console.log(fd.getAll('images'));
      const uploadHandler = unstable_composeUploadHandlers(
        async ({ name, data }) => {
          console.log(name);
          if (name !== "images") {
            return undefined
          }

        const uploadedImage = await uploadImage(data);
        return uploadedImage.secure_url;
      },
        unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler()
      );

      const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
        request,
        uploadHandler
      );

      return formData.getAll('images');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    }
};
```

[image]

On all other browsers it works and its only at file uploading so, idk what I am doing wrong and I cant hard test because I dont have a macbook I have to use a live macos Tester with 10minutes left times and everytime uploading new files in my deployment